# Is it possible to implement an interface with PHP 8 attribute and check if it is an instance of that interface?

Tags: php, reflection, php-8

I have an PHP attribute as follow:

```php
#[Attribute(Attribute::TARGET_PROPERTY|Attribute::TARGET_METHOD|Attribute::TARGET_PARAMETER)]
class NotNull implements Constraint{
 ...
}
```

Now, I want to get the list of all attributes of a property reflection and check if they are instance of Constraint:

```php
$propertyReflection = ...;
$attributes = $propertyReflection->getAttributes();
foreach($attributes as $attribute){
    if($attribute instanceof Constraint){
         // do something
    }
}
```

However, it does nothing?

So, my question is: is it possible to implement an interface with an attribute and then check if the attribute is an instance?

---

Here is a full code:

```php
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($type);
$properties = $reflection->getProperties();
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $attributes = $property->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if (attribute instanceof Constraint)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the line `$propertyReflection = ...;` actually say? I am assuming you are using Reflectors instead of the actual objects?

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because `$attribute` is a `ReflectionAttribute` object that is not yet an instance of your `NotNull` class. To fix this, you need to instance it and check then if its the correct instance.

```
if($attribute->newInstance() instanceof Constraint)
    // do something
```

You can see it working over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fFl3X).

---

If you do not want to instance this for any particular reason for it doing things you do not think necessary, you can also check the attribute is your expected class using more [reflection techniques](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.implementsinterface.php).

```
(new ReflectionClass($attribute->getName()))
    ->implementsInterface(Constraint::class)
```

See this working over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/72aJN)

Comment: Thank you, you save my time. You know, the PHP8 document is not cover all parts of the new features.

Comment: A lot of it exists within the documentation but not specifically, you have to really debug and then research as you go along. If you `var_dump($attriubte)`, you'll see that its not an instance of `NotNull` but glad to help.